# Is it okay to fill in the blanks of 那种汽车 ____ 价钱很贵， ____ 的确质量很好 with 虽然……但是 despite the 的确?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This is a fill-in-the-blanks exercise on page 56 of 新实用汉语课本5 ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPAdc.jpg)):

> 那种汽车 ____ 价钱很贵， ____ 的确质量很好。

We're asked to fill in the blanks with 关联词语.  What's tripping me up here: if the 的确 weren't there, I would use 虽然……但是…… such as in:

> 那种汽车**虽然**价钱很贵，**但是**质量很好。

I'm fairly confident this is unproblematic.

But the given sentence has 的确, and my 语感 is telling me that 虽然……但是…… is not compatible with 的确 here (something feels off, although I can't quite pinpoint what), and I should choose something else.  Although maybe I'm "afraid of ghosts", and the 的确 simply adds emphasis to the right-hand side.

**Question**: Is it okay to fill in the blanks of 那种汽车 ____ 价钱很贵， ____ 的确质量很好 with 虽然……但是 despite the 的确?

Comment: I would say: 那种汽车虽然价钱很贵，但是质量的确很好。

Answer (score 3):

Why not? 的确 is roughly "indeed", it means you admit or agree to a certain fact, or you are very impressed by a certain fact. There's nothing incompatible with 虽然 (although) and 但是 (but).

If I were to write this sentence I would probably use 但是质量的确很好, but 但是的确质量很好 does not sound wrong to me.

The CCL corpus contains usages of both "虽然的确" and "但是的确". Here are a few examples:

> 你一共做过多少个节目自己肯定数不过来吧？
>
> 还好，还可以数过来，**但是的确**蛮多的。

> 我知道施政虽然已经有进步,**但是的确**有不足之处,需要改进。

> 这些所谓“化石”里所含的碳,**虽然的确**与生命活动产生的碳有些类似,但也有可能是特殊的地质活动的产物。

> 他考虑到诡计的可能性，声音**虽然的确**是尤里安的声音，但或许尤里安是在无法自主的情况下，被强迫与敌人合作的。